# change app store application into coming soon

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an application which is done in flutter, I published into the appstore and it accepted after some days. but I now want to change the application screen to coming soon, I made that screen and it is working, but I don't know if the appstore accepts that (coming soon screen) or not!
because the app contains the screenshots of the working app and not coming soon!

Comment: In my opinion, I think you can't, cause you have to bypass Apple review team, and they will not let you do that.  You can try to do a trick like toggle a key from Backend side, then show/hide the coming soon screen. However, I'm not sure if this will violate Apple policy.

Comment: No, you can't have that content. It will be rejected https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-completeness

Comment: hey @Paulw11 , does it says coming soon apps will not accepted? thanks man

Comment: Well, yeah.  Your app must be *fully functional* - "Submissions to App Review, including apps you make available for pre-order, should be final versions with all necessary metadata and fully functional URLs included; placeholder text, empty websites, and other temporary content should be scrubbed before submission.". "Coming soon" is temporary content

Comment: Or you can submit your update and see what happens, but I can guarantee it will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it will be rejected. one of my apps got rejected because one of the features only marked as `coming soon`

Answer (score 0):

fortunately, the app accepted haha, I don't know how, but accepted, it was 2:30 AM went into review, then after about 10 minutes approved to the appstore ;)